# bookTest.java prints out author arrayList, but not isbn

Tags: java, arraylist, isbn

**Requirements:** accommodate multiple authors using one of the components from the Java Collection Framework.  Requires one book with an isbn and a Collection of authors. JUnit: Guidance for testValidate: Test for at least two cases (one case where the book properties hold the correct data types and are not empty nor hold a null value, one where they do not). Guidance for testEquals: Test for at least two cases (one case where authors and isbn match, one where they do not). Test for at least two authors. My teacher told me: testEquals you need to add isbn and two authors. Create an ArrayList. Add two authors to it. Create a Book object and add the ArrayList instance and the isbn. I think that's what I have done, the authors are printing, but the ISBNs are not. I am a total newbie and I am at a loss! Can anyone help?

**EDIT/ADDITION** I got the ISBN to print, but it is only printing the second isbn I have. What do I need to change to get both of them to print? Or does it matter?

**Here is the output:**

```
Testsuite: library.domain.BookTest
equals
Author List: [Bob Smith, Jane Doe]
ISBN: 67890
validate
Author List: [Bob Smith, Jane Doe]
ISBN: 67890
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.23 sec

------------- Standard Output ---------------
equals
Author List: [Bob Smith, Jane Doe]
ISBN: 67890
validate
Author List: [Bob Smith, Jane Doe]
ISBN: 67890
------------- ---------------- ---------------
test:
Deleting: /var/folders/k7/wpgy3lw91171qxlzt4pj0cfh0000gn/T/TEST-library.domain.BookTest.xml
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Here is my new page:

**NEW BookTest.java**

```
package library.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BookTest {

    private ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Test
    public void testEquals()                //test Equals() for accuracy
    {
        System.out.println("equals");
        authorList.add("Bob Smith");
        Book book = new Book("12345", authorList);
        assertEquals("expected true", true, book.equals(book));
        authorList.add("Jane Doe");
        book = new Book("67890", authorList);
        assertEquals("expected true", true, book.equals(book));
        System.out.println("Author List: " + authorList);
        System.out.println("ISBN: " + book.getIsbn());
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidate()          //test Validate() for accuracy
    {
        System.out.println("validate");
        authorList.add("Bob Smith");
        Book book = new Book("12345", authorList);
        assertEquals("expected true", true, book.validate());
        authorList.add("Jane Doe");
        book = new Book("67890", authorList);
        assertEquals("expected true", true, book.validate());
        System.out.println("Author List: " + authorList);
        System.out.println("ISBN: " + book.getIsbn());
    }
}
```

**Book.java**

```
package library.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private ArrayList<String> authorList;

    public Book(String isbn, ArrayList<String> authorList)
    {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.authorList = authorList;
    }

    public String getIsbn()             //access to isbn and manages  next value
    {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn)            //assigns the input isbn to the data member isbn
    {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
//assigns the input author to the data member author

    public ArrayList<String> getAuthorList()
    {
        return authorList;
    }

    public void setAuthorList(ArrayList<String> authorList)
    {
        this.authorList = authorList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)           //checks  equality of two objects - true if same, false if different
    {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Book)) {
            return false;
        }

        Book book = (Book) obj;
        if (!this.isbn.equals(book.isbn)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.authorList.equals(book.authorList)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()           //override hash
    {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.authorList);
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.isbn);
        return hash;
    }

    public boolean validate()           //validate isbn and author not null
    {
        if (isbn == null || isbn.equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (authorList == null || authorList.equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**BookTest.java**

```
package library.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BookTest {

    private ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String isbn;

    @Test
    public void testEquals()                //test Equals() for accuracy
    {
        System.out.println("equals");
        authorList.add("Bob Smith");
        authorList.add("Jane Doe");
        Book book = new Book("12345", authorList);
        assertEquals("expected true", true, book.equals(book));
        System.out.println("Author List: " + authorList);
        System.out.println("ISBN: " + isbn);
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidate()          //test Validate() for accuracy
    {
        System.out.println("validate");
        authorList.add("Bob Smith");
        authorList.add("Jane Doe");
        Book book = new Book("12345", authorList);
        assertEquals("expected true", true, book.validate());
        System.out.println("Author List: " + authorList);
        System.out.println("ISBN: " + isbn);
    }
}
```

Comment: `isbn` is available in `book` class and `authorList` in current class.

Comment: to make @Satya 's comment more clear: You have a local variable called `isbn` but you don't put a value in. You should remove it and call `book.getIsbn()` instead.

Comment: `isbn` is not initialized in the `BookTest` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isbn in the test class is a local variable and you are not setting any values for the same. To check if object is being created correctly, try printing book.getAuthorList() and book.getIsbn()

Comment: This worked! Thank you SOOOO MUCH!  Now onto the next part of my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

`Book book = new Book("12345", authorList);`

Here you are setting value to `isbn` is available in `Book` class.

```
   System.out.println("ISBN: " + isbn);
```

But here you are trying print `isbn` which is present in current class. So it doesn't print any value. Since you are not pass any value to it.

To print value of `isbn`, available in `Book` class write

```
   System.out.println("ISBN: " + book.getIsbn());


   System.out.println("Author List: " + authorList);
```

Here also `authorList` is a local variable. To print value of `authorList` is available in `Book` class wirte

```
   System.out.println("Author List: " + book.authorList());
```

Comment: I changed to print book.isbn and got the errors:  testEquals(library.domain.BookTest): 
Uncompilable source code - isbn has private access in library.domain.Book

Comment: I updated my answer. call `book.getIsbn()` and `book.authorList()`. since `isbn` is `private` variable. so we can't access outside of class like `book.isbn`.

Answer (score 0):

In BookTest you are printing out the value of the isbn in the scope of BookTest. You initialized it in BookTest so any calls to isbn will refer to the global variable

```
private String isbn;
```

You need to print out the isbn field of the Book object.

```
System.out.println("ISBN: " + book.getIsbn());
```

You had the getter method written, you just forgot to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the `ISBN` and `authorList` you should use their getter methods. In your test there is no `String` object named `ISBN`. Instead use `book.getIsbn();`

Some other things:

In the `validate()` method; authorList is a `List` not a `String` so `authorList.equals("")` will never return true. You should do something like `authorList.size() == 0`. Also the `return true` doesn't need to be within `{}`.

Also you shouldn't just try to print a list (`System.out.println("Author List: " + authorList);`). You could get very unexpected results.